# Read and store file content in a double array

Tags: java

I need to write a program that reads and stores an inputted file in Java in a double array. The number of values in the file is stored in the first line of the file, then the actual data values follow.

Here is what I have so far:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException
{
    Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Please enter the name of the input file: ");
    String inputFileName = console.next();

    Scanner in = new Scanner(inputFileName);

    int n = in.nextInt();
    double[] array = new double[n];

    for( int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
    {
        array[i] = in.nextDouble();
    }

    console.close();
}
```

Input File is as follows:

> 10
>   43628.45
>   36584.94
>   76583.47
>   36585.34
>   86736.45
>   46382.50
>   34853.02
>   46378.43
>   34759.42
>   37658.32

As of now, regardless of the file name I input, I am getting an exception message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
    at Project6.main(Project.java:33)
```

Comment: Which line in the code snippet above corresponds to line 33?

Comment: int n = in.nextInt();

Comment: @coscdummy Can you include the input file in your question?

Comment: I guess you need `Scanner in = new Scanner(new File(inputFileName));`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the following code. Scanner must be provided with `File` instead of just `String` as shown in the following snippet:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Please enter the name of the input file: ");
        String inputFileName = console.nextLine();

        Scanner in = null;
        try {
            in = new Scanner(new File(inputFileName));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        int n = in.nextInt();
        double[] array = new double[n];

        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            array[i] = in.nextDouble();
        }
        for (double d : array) {
            System.out.println(d); 
        }
        console.close();
    }
}
```

Sample output:

> Please enter the name of the input file: c:/hadoop/sample.txt
>   43628.45
>   36584.94
>   76583.47
>   36585.34
>   86736.45
>   46382.5
>   34853.02
>   46378.43
>   34759.42
>   37658.32

Comment: Please don't just post some code. Explain why it should work for OP. Btw this code looks untested.

Comment: `System.out.printlN(d);`

Comment: Thank you! The code outputted was correct now when inputting the detailed path but I receive an error when I only input the file name.  Is this because of where I am saving it or an error in my code??

Comment: That's a very Good Question. Its not a bug in program. It's time for you to explore about Absolute path and relative path. ;-)

Answer (score 8):

`new Scanner(String)` constructor scans the specified String. Not the file denoted by the pathname in the string.

If you want to scan the file, use

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(new File(inputFileName));
```

Comment: I changed that line and I am still getting error messages: 
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: inputValues.txt (The system cannot find the file specified)
 at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
 at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Unknown Source)
 at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.Scanner.<init>(Unknown Source)
 at Project6.main(Project6.java:33)

Comment: The message is clear... It's not able to find the file `inputValues.txt` you specified... Try giving an absolute path name instead of relative...